# Best approach to fetch data in every state of app

Tags: ember.js

I've discovered this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLHuG/) and I'm now wondering what the best approach would be to display the list of contributors both in the `IndexRoute` and in all Subroutes of `match('/contributor/:contributor_id')` with the new v2 Router from Ember.js.

The problem I'm experiencing is that

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Contributor.find();
    }
});​
```

is only fetching the data on the specified `/` route.

When directly navigating to `/#/contributor/[some_id]` the data for the `IndexRoute` doesn't get loaded and the user would first have to navigate to `/` to see the list of contributors.

The only possible solution I've come to is to have a `ContributorsView` which gets called called in the `application` template. Meanwhile I don't know how to populate this view with data, as a view doesn't have the `model` property which the route has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not yet confortable with the new router implementation, but from a design point of view, I would use a different structure for the routes, for example by adding a contributors route, accessible from the index, and perhaps directly redirect to contributors. 
Then you have always the contributors displayed, and when clicking on one of them you could see the details. A kind of master/detail blocks.

Here the router map:

```
App.Router.map(function(match){
  match('/').to('home');
  match('/about').to('about');
  match('/contributors').to('contributors', function(match){
    match('/').to('contributorsIndex');
    match('/:contributor_id').to('contributor', function(match){
      match('/').to('contributorIndex');
      match('/details').to('contributorDetail');
      match('/repos').to('contributorRepos');
    });
  });
});
```

Here is what I would do: http://jsfiddle.net/JLHuG/21/ does it work for you ?

Comment: This is great, thanks! Actually, I've tried a very similar way to do this (before the approach with the view) but I forgot to pass the `match` param in the nested routes. :D