# How to nest views in the new Ember.js router API?

Tags: ember.js

I have a setup screen, it consists of a sidebar and a body. The body can have a form to update the user's profile or password.

The routing looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function(match) {
  (match("/")).to("index");
  (match("/user")).to("user", function(match) {
    (match("/")).to("userIdx");
    (match("/settings")).to("userSetup", function(match) {
      (match("/")).to("userSetupIdx");
      (match("/profile")).to("userSetupProfile");
      (match("/password")).to("userSetupPassword");
    });
  });
});
```

and the wrapping setup template like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="userSetup">
  <div class='sidebar'>
    Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class='main'>
    Setup <br/>
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</script>
```

A complete example can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/stephanos/mgp7F/6/

*What's the right approach to do this in Ember.js?*

**EDIT**

With the help of sly7_7 I managed to make the fiddle above work: http://jsfiddle.net/ygvsS/9/. All I did was rename everything from `userSetup` (template, view, route) to `setup`. BUT obviously this is not a solution (since I have appSetup, too).

Comment: I found this fiddle which does something similar (http://jsfiddle.net/mhfs/Y93qQ/8/) - it seems the outlet is "automagically" connected to when the names of the template and route match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have done what you are looking for, based on your comment example: http://jsfiddle.net/rt8fv/

router code:

```
App.Router.map(function(match){
  match('/').to('home');
  match('/about').to('about');
  match('/contributors').to('contributors', function(match){
    match('/').to('contributorsIndex');
    match('/:contributor_id').to('contributor', function(match){
      match('/').to('contributorIndex');
      match('/details').to('contributorDetail');
      match('/repos').to('contributorRepos');
    });
  });
});
```

Maybe related question: [Best approach to fetch data in every state of app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125456/best-approach-to-fetch-data-in-every-state-of-app/)

Comment: I around played a bit with my code and it seems (!) that when my template/view is called "setup" it works, and when it's called "userSetup" it doesn't - bug ?

Comment: I scare I don't really understand what you want exactly. Could you update your question, describing which screens with which content you expect?

Comment: I don't know which version of ember you use, but if its before https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/3920af6a018ac6147e5534049b751ff0b4eeaae3, you should use underscored template name only

Comment: I'm using _the_ lastest ember from master

Comment: what I want is actually simple: make the example (http://jsfiddle.net/stephanos/mgp7F/6/) work - without changing the meaning of the names :)

Comment: Is this http://jsfiddle.net/mgp7F/12/ working ? As you can see here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L36, defining redirect and using transitionTo stops the routing flow for this route, so templates are not rendered. Is this what you mean by this is not working ?